# "Top up your phone with an ATM," "top up your phone through an ATM," "top up your phone at ATM" or "top up your phone from an ATM"?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me which one of the following sentences is the most correct and natural?

> If you don't have mobile data, you can always top up your phone **with** an ATM.
>
> If you don't have mobile data, you can always top up your phone **through** an ATM.
>
> If you don't have mobile data, you can always top up your phone **at** an ATM.
>
> If you don't have mobile data, you can always top up your phone
> **from** an ATM.

Is there any difference in meaning between the four?

Comment: Personally, I'd use 'at'.

Comment: All of those work, albeit each with different effect. It depends entirely on what effect you wish to convey, for example, if the effect is a person conveniently being able to go to an ATM to do it, I'd use "at," but if the effect is it's something a person can conveniently do while already at an ATM machine, like as part of a typical trip to an ATM to withdraw cash, make a deposit, etc., I'd use "from." Like I said, each of those has a different effect, so if you want an answer, not just comments, please provide some context and explain what effect you wish to convey.